# 'cocoapods' how to edit podspec file

Tags: ios, cocoapods, automatic-ref-counting, podspec

Example taken from https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#requires_arc:

```
spec.requires_arc = ['Classes/*ARC.m', 'Classes/ARC.mm']
```

What is the meaning of the following？ Can you give an example that to use? Thanks!

```
Classes/*ARC.m 
Classes/ARC.mm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the Cocoapods documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#tab_requires_arc) (which you're presumably looking at right now), your choices are "`true`", "`false`" or the actual files that require ARC ([automated-ref-counting](/questions/tagged/automated-ref-counting)).

So for the Podspec pattern `spec.requires_arc = ['Classes/*ARC.m', 'Classes/ARC.mm']` you'd be saying that any files in the "Classes" directory that are either named `ARC.mm` or `*ARC.m` (i.e. * being a wildcard so "`ChenFanFangARC.m` would be a valid match while `ARCMichael.m` is not), these files are expected to work with Automated Reference Counting.

All other files compiled for this pod would have ARC turned off.